# the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to object java

Tags: java, arrays, typecasting-operator

I want to print out the numbers at index 1 from each `bills[][]` array.
For example, 7 in `bills[0][1] = new Bill("Carrot", 7, 2000)`.
It says "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Bill." What should I do?

```
package Module6;

    public class Bill {
        
        String name;
        int numberCheckedOutPerItem;
        int pricePerItem;
        
        
        Bill (String name, int ...v){
            this.name = name;
            this.numberCheckedOutPerItem =numberCheckedOutPerItem;
            this.pricePerItem = pricePerItem;
        }
    
    }
```

```
package Module6;

    public class CashRegister {
        
        private Bill[][] bills; 
        CashRegister(){
            bills = new Bill[4][3];
            
            bills[0][0] = new Bill("Cucumber", 4, 5000);
            bills[0][1] = new Bill("Carrot", 7, 2000);
            bills[0][2] = new Bill("Onion", 11, 1500);
            
            bills[1][0] = new Bill("Cucumber", 8, 5000);
            bills[1][1] = new Bill("Carrot", 18, 2000);
            bills[1][2] = new Bill("Onion", 3, 1500);
            
            bills[2][0] = new Bill("Cucumber", 2, 5000);
            bills[2][1] = new Bill("Carrot", 7, 2000);
            bills[2][2] = new Bill("Onion", 6, 1500);
            
            bills[3][0] = new Bill("Cucumber", 9, 5000);
            bills[3][1] = new Bill("Carrot", 13, 2000);
            bills[3][2] = new Bill("Onion", 20, 1500);
            
        }
    
    **void getItems() {
        int totalNum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<bills.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<bills[i].length; j++) {
                for(int k=0; k<bills[i][j].length; k++) {
                totalNum = totalNum + (int) bills[i][j][2];
                }**
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: How does your Bill class look like?

Comment: Also what do you mean by ? ```I want to print out the number at index 1```

Comment: As your `Bill` is not an array, you cannot just get the item like `bills[i][j][2];`. This doesn't work. You retrieve your `Bill` object like `bills[i][j]` and then retrieve your desired field from the object either via a getter or directly if the field is public.